# Why does kmeans after SVD result in ideal clusters

Tags: clustering, pca, k-means, svd

I am clustering tweets which are related to eye fashion and they are extracted using keywords like mascara, eyeliner, eyeshadow, etc from twitter. 
I 
constructed a Tf-idf matrix (tweets x words) which was around (100000 x 550).

If I give this to K-Means and plot elbow plot I don't get a perfect elbow. (Its almost diagonal)
But after applying truncated SVD with latent variables say 10 variables and then I do kmeans, I get a perfect elbow at 10.

I have tested this for various other numbers of latent variables too and I get perfect elbow at those numbers.
Can the results be trusted in this case?

I don't see the clusters having similar topics. What is the best way to proceed in this case.
I did try LDA but there also I dont see perfect distinction between topics.
Is it because that the data itself is not clusterable?

Comment: This question can hardly be answered without the example: your data, your analysis, results, pics.

Comment: Tweets *tend* to not be clusterable with k-means well. They are too short and there is too much garbage on Twitter (and k-means does not tolerate noise well). Tough luck.